# Does changing in `lsb-release` file affects upgrades?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, release-management

I have Ubuntu and Edubuntu installed on my laptop. But both shows as "Ubuntu ..." in the grub menu.

To workaround this, I can change the variable `DISTRIB_ID` and `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION` to have values "Edubuntu" instead of "Ubuntu" and then run `sudo update-grub`. But, I wonder whether that can affect my future upgrades.

For example, If I want to upgrade to a latest release, will that upgrade be done as an "Ubuntu" system or "Edubuntu" system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this file doesn't affect the upgrade. I saw the same string `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu` in Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu and Edubuntu installation. So, this file really doesn't play any role in the upgrade process in deciding the flavor of Ubuntu. But of course, it decide the versions of (X)Ubuntu